# Mono DllImport libsmbclient not authenticating

Tags: c#, mono, samba, libsmbclient

I need to be able to access a Samba/Cifs share from Mono using specific credentials.

The best option I've found so far is to use libsmbclient. Unfortunately, I can't get it to authenticate. To rule out firewall/security/etc, I've tried using the `smbclient` executable which can connect without issue.

The low-level DLLImport stuff and some hard-coded creds for testing...

```
public static void Initialise() {
    log.Trace("Initialising libsmbclient wrapper");
    try {
        smbc_init(callbackAuth, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.Trace(String.Format("{0}: {1}", e.GetType().Name, e.ToString()));
        throw;
    }
}

public static void callbackAuth(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String server,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String share,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String workgroup, int workgroupMaxLen,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String username, int usernameMaxLen,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String password, int passwordMaxLen) {
    server = "targetserver";
    share = "Public";
    username = "Management.Service";
    password = @"{SomeComplexPassword}";
    workgroup = "targetserver";
    usernameMaxLen = username.Length;
    passwordMaxLen = password.Length;
    workgroupMaxLen = workgroup.Length;
}

[DllImport("libsmbclient.so", SetLastError = true)]
extern internal static int smbc_init(smbCGetAuthDataFn callBackAuth, int debug);

[DllImport("libsmbclient.so", SetLastError = true)]
extern internal static int smbc_opendir([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String durl);
```

I'm attempting to use it like this...

```
public bool DirectoryExists(string path) {
    log.Trace("Checking directory exists {0}", path);
    int handle;
    string fullpath = @"smb:" + parseUNCPath(path);
    handle = SambaWrapper.smbc_opendir(fullpath);
    if (handle < 0) {
    var error = Stdlib.GetLastError().ToString();
        if (error == "ENOENT"
           |error == "EINVAL")
            return false;
        else
            throw new Exception(error);
    } else {
    WrapperSambaClient.smbc_close(fd);
    return true;
}
}
```

the `Initialise()` call succeeds but when `DirectoryExists` calls `SambaWrapper.smbc_opendir(fullpath)` I get a negative handle and throw the following exception...

> Slurpy.Exceptions.FetchException: Exception: Failed to fetch: EACCES > (file:////targetserver/Public/ValidSubfolder) ---> System.Exception: EACCES

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way I can debug this?

**Edit:** It seems the issues is that the values from the auth callback have no effect (but the callback is definitely being called as a log statement in there is processed). I'm wondering if it's something to do with the immutability of strings and a new string instance being created with the new values rather than overwriting the old?

**Edit:** Full debug output from libsmbclient attempting to connect removed. You can see it in the edit history if required.

As requested, the definition of the method from the headers...

```
/**@ingroup misc
 * Initialize the samba client library.
 *
 * Must be called before using any of the smbclient API function
 *  
 * @param fn        The function that will be called to obtaion 
 *                  authentication credentials.
 *
 * @param debug     Allows caller to set the debug level. Can be
 *                  changed in smb.conf file. Allows caller to set
 *                  debugging if no smb.conf.
 *   
 * @return          0 on success, < 0 on error with errno set:
 *                  - ENOMEM Out of memory
 *                  - ENOENT The smb.conf file would not load
 *
 */

int smbc_init(smbc_get_auth_data_fn fn, int debug);

/**@ingroup callback
 * Authentication callback function type (traditional method)
 * 
 * Type for the the authentication function called by the library to
 * obtain authentication credentals
 *
 * For kerberos support the function should just be called without
 * prompting the user for credentials. Which means a simple 'return'
 * should work. Take a look at examples/libsmbclient/get_auth_data_fn.h
 * and examples/libsmbclient/testbrowse.c.
 *
 * @param srv       Server being authenticated to
 *
 * @param shr       Share being authenticated to
 *
 * @param wg        Pointer to buffer containing a "hint" for the
 *                  workgroup to be authenticated.  Should be filled in
 *                  with the correct workgroup if the hint is wrong.
 * 
 * @param wglen     The size of the workgroup buffer in bytes
 *
 * @param un        Pointer to buffer containing a "hint" for the
 *                  user name to be use for authentication. Should be
 *                  filled in with the correct workgroup if the hint is
 *                  wrong.
 * 
 * @param unlen     The size of the username buffer in bytes
 *
 * @param pw        Pointer to buffer containing to which password 
 *                  copied
 * 
 * @param pwlen     The size of the password buffer in bytes
 *           
 */
typedef void (*smbc_get_auth_data_fn)(const char *srv, 
                                      const char *shr,
                                      char *wg, int wglen, 
                                      char *un, int unlen,
                                      char *pw, int pwlen);
```

Comment: Have you tried calling from unmanaged code to rule out any possible issues with the p/invoke?

Comment: Looks like your interop code is OK, but you need to get permissions. Look for permissions-authentication functions in Samba documentation. Reproduce the same problem in native code and ask different question, only about Samba and authentication. Then translate the solution to C#.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good point, no I haven't. I assumed that's what smbclient was doing but I've got no proof. I'll give it a spin, thanks

Comment: Ok, after further digging, the values passed in `callbackAuth` have no effect (but the method is definitely called as a log statement in there is executed). I'm wondering if it's something to do with the immutability of strings? Perhaps when I'm setting `username = "Management.Service";`, it's creating a new string instance with the username and the original string is unmodified?

Comment: You might need to specify them as ref string or StringBuilder

Comment: Have you tried marking parameters in callbackAuth with [Out], pass StringBuilder instead of string, or adding ref modifier? How unmanaged code expects output from callback - does it pass buffers for login info, or expects returned buffer pointers?

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately, my C++ skills are negligible and we're at the edge of my knowledge. The [headers are here](ftp://pserver.samba.org/pub/unpacked/samba_3_next/source3/include/libsmbclient.h), I've copied what I believe are the relevant auth parts into my question. If you can see anything obvious, please let me know

Comment: Ok, changing all the parameters to be `ref string` causes a `Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application`, changing to StringBuilder doesn't _seem_ to make any difference from plain string. ref StringBuilder on the other hand, gives a `Assertion at marshal.c:7242, condition `!t->byref' not met` and a SIGABRT.

Comment: Well looking at the headers it looks like `srv` and `share` are read only. That would make (assuming we got ref string/StringBuilder right) `server = "targetserver"; share = "Public";` wrong.

Comment: Getting warmer.. srv/share are already populated correctly, presumably due to the `smbc_opendir` call parsing them from the path. The other parameters have default values too (eg username is `root`). Using a SB parameter and then appending `test` to the username (so it contains roottest) still results in it using `root` as the username in the debug trace (assuming I'm reading it right). At the end of the auth callback, I'm seeing the following from my logging: `Configured Creds: MYGROUPDOMAIN(13)\rootmanagement.service(22) for //targetserver/public`. Numbers in brackets represent lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your callback gets invoked by libsmbclient, and it is passing 
buffer and its length from unmanaged code, expecting you to populate username and password.
Since this allocated memory is controlled by calling side, you cannot use string 
or stringbuilder. I suggest to use IntPtr, and populate buffer on lowest possible level.

(On the other hand, server and share are read-only strings, and not expected to change,
so we can keep them string).

```
public static void callbackAuth(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String server,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String share,
    IntPtr workgroup, int workgroupMaxLen,
    IntPtr username, int usernameMaxLen,
    IntPtr password, int passwordMaxLen) 
{
    //server = "targetserver";
    //share = "Public"; 
    // should not be assigned - 
    // you must provide credentials for specified server

    SetString(username, "Management.Service", username.Length);
    SetString(password, @"{SomeComplexPassword}", password.Length);
    SetString(workgroup, "targetserver", workgroup.Length);
}

private void SetString(IntPtr dest, string str, int maxLen)
{
    // include null string terminator
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str + "\0");
    if (buffer.Length >= maxLen) return; // buffer is not big enough

    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, dest, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: I had a vague idea of the problem re: strings but not how to solve it so thanks, that definitely pointed me in the right direction. The log files now show something _like_ the input strings... my domain name `ABCDEF` is being shown in the logs as `ABCDEFP` (7 chars as per the default `MYGROUP` instead of desired 6). Conversely username  is having the last char truncated (`Management.Servic`, default `root`). I've tried treating the ints as Length not MaxLength parameters (eg setting to value lengths of 6/17 respectively) but this doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: The log entry relating to wg/domain name says `DomainNameLen: 0x000e (14), DomainNameMaxLen: 0x000e (14), DomainName: *, DomainName: 'ABCDEFP'`. With 14 being 2x the 7-char value it has, I'm wondering if it's a unicode issue or similar?

Comment: Is DomainName a workgroup name in code? If so, you need to set last char to zero byte - C code uses zero-terminated strings. I will update answer to include this. Regarding user name length - can you dump usernameMaxLen and passwordMaxLen? What is the buffers size passed to callback?

Comment: Null-terminating strings did the trick. There are some other issues but it's connecting so I can sort the rest out. Thank you very much for your help. Enjoy the bounty, it was worth every point.

Comment: hey @Alexander and Basic, i created https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12128 related to this.
can you possibly fork this repo https://github.com/nddipiazza/SambaFetcher and add your example to it so that others can use your work?